# How to join arrays with mpi4py?

Tags: python, csv, mpi, mpi4py

I'm new using MPI and I'm trying to parallelize the following code with MPI4PY. It's a code that read more or less 100 csv files and rearrange them.
The problem comes after the parallelization how to **join in order** the arrays 'data' and 'mapData'
the original code without parallelization:

```
import csv
import sys
import numpy as np
import StringIO 
import re

numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
def numericalSort(value):
parts = numbers.split(value)
parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
return parts
#def sprintf(buf, fmt, *args):
#    buf.write(fmt % args)
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import os,glob
folder = os.getcwd()+'/'
files_in_dir=[]
for i in sorted(glob.glob('*.csv'), key=numericalSort):
    print "Current File Being Processed is: " + i
    files_in_dir.append(i)
filelist = [[]] * len(files_in_dir) 
for file in xrange(len(files_in_dir)):
    fileName = folder+files_in_dir[file]
    with open(fileName, 'rt') as f:
        has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(f.read(1024))
        f.seek(0)  # rewind
        incsv = csv.reader(f)
        if has_header:
                next(incsv)
        reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) 
        for row in reader:
        #next(reader)
                filelist[file].append(row) #save each row
               # for row in 
        f.close()
        filelist = [sorted(filelist[ijk],key = lambda x: x[7]) for ijk in xrange(len(filelist))] #order row by numerical index
    # DO NOT!!! use P

data = [[]]*len(filelist[0])  #len(filelist[0])=lunghezza colonna
mapData = [[]]*len(filelist[0])
for i in xrange(len(data)):
    data[i] = [filelist[k][i][0:4] for k in xrange(len(filelist))]
    mapData[i] =  filelist[0][i][4:7] 

with open('mapdata.csv', 'wb') as mapdatares:
       writer = csv.writer(mapdatares)
       writer.writerows(mapData)
```

and this is what I could have done. my problem is when I call 'comm.allreduce'

```
import csv
import sys
import numpy as np
import StringIO 
import re
from mpi4py import MPI
from mpi4py.MPI import ANY_SOURCE

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
def numericalSort(value):
    parts = numbers.split(value)
    parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
    return parts
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import os,glob
import math
folder = os.getcwd()+'/'
files_in_dir=[]
for i in sorted(glob.glob('*.csv'), key=numericalSort):
    print "Current File Being Processed is: " + 1
    files_in_dir.append(i)

    #count number of csv files
    print "number of files is: ", len(files_in_dir)

    #divide files for processors
    filesrank=len(files_in_dir)/size
    intero=math.trunc(filesrank)
fremain=len(files_in_dir) % size
if fremain > rank:
    sizeproc=intero + 1
else:
    sizeproc=intero

#extreme of intervals
a=rank * sizeproc
b=a + sizeproc

#parallelize

filelist = [[]] * len(files_in_dir[a:b])
for file in xrange(len(files_in_dir[a:b])):
    fileName = folder+files_in_dir[file]
    with open(fileName, 'rt') as f:
        has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(f.read(1024))
        f.seek(0)  # rewind
        incsv = csv.reader(f)
        if has_header:
            next(incsv)
        reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) #read cvs file skipping reader
        for row in reader:
        #next(reader)
                filelist[file].np.append(row) #save each row
               # for row in 
        f.close()
        filelist = [sorted(filelist[ijk],key = lambda x: x[7]) for ijk in xrange(len(filelist))] #order row by numerical index

data = [[]]*len(filelist[0])  #len(filelist[0])=lunghezza colonna
mapData = [[]]*len(filelist[0])
for i in xrange(len(data)):
    data= [filelist[k][i][0:4] for k in xrange(len(filelist))]
    mapData =  filelist[0][i][4:7] 

totmapData = []
totData = []
comm.allreduce(mapData, totmapData, op=MPI.SUM)
comm.allreduce(data, totData, op=MPI.SUM)
```

Any suggestion? thanks